# How to pass my broadcast receiver context class to my service class

Tags: sms, broadcast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Static Way to get Context on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android)

I have a broadcast receiver class and service class and  I am starting my service inside my broadcast receiver if I receive a string "testing".

THis is how I start my service inside my broadcast receiver class. It's working

```
private void startSMSforwarderService(Context context,String y)
{
    if(y.startsWith("testing"))
    {
        Intent SmsForwarderService = new Intent(context,SmsForwarderService.class);
        SmsForwarderService.putExtra("var_msgbody",msgbody); //pass variable value via intent from broadcast receiver to android service
        SmsForwarderService.putExtra("var_from", from);

        context.startService(SmsForwarderService);
    }
}
```

I have a method inside my service that needs context and I want to extend my context from  my broadcast receiver to my service. How could I do that? Some snippet  would much appreciated.. Thanks

my receiver
https://gist.github.com/3171877

My service class

https://gist.github.com/3171792

As you can see I have a method inside my service and it needs a context before I can use that..

```
void forwardSMS(String msgbody,Context smsSenderService, Intent SENT_ACTION)
```

Basically I want to pass my broadcast receiver context to my service class....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.. I found this  [Static way to get 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android)

but is their another way to do it?